# Can i use smartphone tethering instead of USB wireless inthernet lan card in Linux?

Tags: usb, smartphone

I am a Newbe in Linux. I will thank you for any account and i wll be really appreciated

---

### Explain my situation

I use inthernet in laptop. 
And When i connect inthernet, i use device that smartphone. 
The smartphone is connected laptop used USB.
Smartphone be activated 'USB tethering'

---

### So

When i command ' sudo ifconfig -a ' I can show 3 list.

first is eth0 : blah blah

second is lo : blah

third is usb0

---

### Question

So if i use smartphone tethering [ smartphone - usb - labtop ] instead of USB wireless inthernet lan card, can't see wlan0 at third line ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a smartphone can provide internet connectivity in two ways: it can either act as a wireless access point, or by USB tethering. In both cases, the smartphone will be using the mobile phone network as its uplink.

When a smartphone is not acting as a wireless access point for other devices, it can act as a wireless client to achieve higher data bandwidth and save on data transfer costs. (In other words, the smartphone can use another wireless access point as its uplink.) But I have not seen a smartphone that could act as a replacement of a wireless network card.

The technical details involved in tethering can vary: older phones provide tethering by modem emulation, while newer ones may provide effectively a USB network interface. But in both cases, the wireless hardware is always under control of the smartphone's own processor: the phone won't allow the tethered computer to take direct control of the phone's Wi-Fi hardware.

And that is why you won't see a tethered smartphone as a `wlan0` device, but possibly ppp0 or usb0, eth1 or similar.

Comment: Yes. I almost understand. i need New USB wlan card. Not smartphone. Thank you telcom.

Comment: Exactly. If you want to connect to a wireless AP with your laptop, you will need a USB wlan card, a smartphone can not be used as a substitute.

Comment: @telcoM My smartphone (Meizu PRO6) is capable of providing USB tethering from a WiFi uplink. Tested without a SIM card just to be sure.